# Is there a way to set the default size of a plot window?

Tags: linux, r

I would like to change the default size of an R plot window. Does anyone know if there is a configuration setting for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the size of the plot window to 600x600, say, add this line to `~/.Xresources`:

```
R_x11*geometry: 600x600
```

and reload the file with

```
$ xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
```

Answer (score 3):

Your default size of a plotting window can be set using `windows.options()` or `X11.options()` with the `width` and `height` parameters. I think setting the defaults using `windows.options()` also sets them for X11 devices, at least on my windows machine. On Linux, X11 is used as a graphics device and thus you should be able to use `X11.options()` for your needs. If you want to save these defaults across R sessions, in the examples of http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/grDevices/html/x11.html you can find a way this can be done.

Comment: Thanks for the input. To be able to set the window size in pixels (rather than inches) I chose the solution (posted here) which adds a configuration setting to `~/.Xresources`.